# asp.net validationgroup on fieldset

Tags: asp.net, validation

is there a way to add a validationgroup to a fieldset, this way i do not have to add a validationgroup attribute to every single validator within that fieldset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as simple as that. Asp.net validators are not aware of the surrounding HTML.

What you might be able to do is assign an id and runat='server' to your fieldset. Then programatically run through each control inside and if it's a validation control, assign your validation group.